# Best way to read binary data in C++ using classes without padding

Tags: c++, class, padding

I am reading simple binary data, without pointers, using C++ classes without padding with the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data {
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
    short int c;
    double d;
}__attribute__((packed));

int main() {
    Data myData;      
    ifstream ifs("test.bin", ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&myData, sizeof(myData));
    ifs.close();
}
```

I am using this method because the data might have 20+ different formats and I want to write 20+ different classes to cover all the formats that might show up. I also read that other options include using bit-fields, pragma directives, and even the boost serialization routines (I can't because I have to use std). My question is: **is this the  best way to read simple binary data using classes without padding? Do you suggest any other alternative?** I would like to learn what is the safest and most widely used method out there.

Comment: There is pretty much no other way that is similarly simple and effective. At least not that I am aware of. Just call `Data` `struct` for good look.

Comment: Your approach is good.  You may consider [`#pragma pack(push,0)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) to allow your code to be supported by more compilers.  Neither approach is guaranteed to be supported by C++ though.

Comment: Drew, that actually addresses my question very well, I am trying to find something that is compiler, cross-platform, safe. So is pragma_pack safer? could you ellaborate a little bit more on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used these macros to allow packed structs to compile on both gcc and VC:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define BEGIN_PACK __pragma( pack(push, 1) )
    #define END_PACK __pragma( pack(pop) )
#else
    #define BEGIN_PACK 
    #define END_PACK __attribute__((packed))
#endif
```

So then you'd use them like this:

```
BEGIN_PACK
struct Data {
    int a;
    int b;
    short int c;
    double d;
} END_PACK;
```

But yes, that's usually how it's done. Note that these are non-standard extensions.

C++11 has defined packing directives, but I don't know if they're supported by compilers yet.

Comment: Yes. clang supports it as well, since it's gcc-compatible. But yes, it's a gcc extension.

Comment: Some compilers have `pshpackX.h` and `poppack.h` header files, where `N` is the desired byte alignment (1, 2, 4, 8, etc), to hide compiler-specific details.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one would use a `struct` instead of a `class`, but yes, the same concept applies to both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but are you sure that using a struct instead of a class is better? I read that in C++, it is recommended to use classes in order to be consistent. I also read that the main difference between a class and a struct is that a class is private by default while a struct is public by default.

Comment: @JaimeCervantes The common convention I've seen is when you have all public member variaible and no getters or setters used, a `struct` is normally used instead of a `class`.